# Which is the correct writing of $\displaystyle\lim_{|s|\to +\infty} \frac{f(x, s, t)}{|s|^{p-2}s}=+\infty$ by using the definition of limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

This question is about an exercise that I have done during my math class. Let $p>1$ and $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and let $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that
$$\lim_{|s|\to +\infty} \frac{f(x, s, t)}{|s|^{p-2}s}=+\infty\quad\text{ uniformly with respect to $t$}.$$

During the test I wrote that this also means that for all $c>0$ there exists a positive constant $L=L(c)$ such that
$$f(x, s, t)\ge c|s|^{p-2}s - L(c) \quad\text{a.e. in } \Omega.$$

The lecturer said it is not correct since $f$ is also a function of $t$ (it would have been correct if it had been $f=f(x, s)$).

So my question is: there is some hypothesis I can assume on $t$ such that "my" inequality remains true also when $f=f(x, s, t)$?
On the other hand, it is possible to deduce from "my" inequality that the above limit holds?

I got nothing for now, could someone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Was there any other context to this? In the limit equation $t$ is an "unbound variable", so the context could be saying that the equation holds for some particular $t$ or for all $t$ in some domain. If the context doesn't say, or if your answer can be taken in the the same context, I might not change your answer to reflect the role of $t$ at all.